# disable links inside pdf embedded on <embed> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, pdf

On my app users can upload a `pdf` file and render it directly in the browser:

```
<embed src="some.pdf" id="pdf-embed" type="application/pdf"/>
```

Now I want to disable all links inside the `pdf` for which have been googling for a while but cannot find a simple solution.

I tried the following:

```
$("#pdf-embed").on("click", "a", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

But doesn't not work, since `#pdf-embed` does not have html content but a source `pdf` (rendered by some `js` classes from the browser).

Comment: Write a server-side app that strip out annotations like links on upload.

Comment: @KevinBrown is correct. Since the embed tag relies on each browser's implementation of PDF viewing, you won't be able to reliably control their experience of the PDF. You'll need to modify the file server-side. Depending on your server environment and skill set, there are any number of libraries you can use.